# Configuring serial driver sc16is7xx

Tags: drivers, tty, embedded, interface

## Initial Question

I work with the NXP chip SC16IS740 as a peripheral to an embedded linux system (mainline kernel v4.8). The usecase is quite simple, a continuosly transmitting uart line (9600 8n1) shall be read via the chip's driver.

So far I included the driver module `sc16is7xx` in the kernel build and I am able to see the device as `/dev/ttySC0`.

However, I cannot read the uart for now and I suspect, I am missing the right configuration. I've tried it both with simply

```
cat /dev/ttySC0
```

and

```
minicom -D /dev/ttySC0 -b 9600 -8
```

Since there are just read-only files in the device's directory (/sys/class/tty/ttySC0/) and I don't find any documentation on how to use the driver, I'm running out of ideas.

What is the proper way of configuring this driver?

---

## Edit: Config, logs & measurements

### Config

I included the module in the kernel recipes config as followed:

```
CONFIG_SERIAL_SC16IS7XX_CORE=m
CONFIG_SERIAL_SC16IS7XX=m
CONFIG_SERIAL_SC16IS7XX_I2C=y
```

To load / unload the module (which results in loading/unloading the device `/dev/ttySC0`) I use:

```
modprobe [-r] sc16is7xx
```

### Logs

Grepping `dmesg` for `sc16is7` results in this kind of messages:

```
[ 5592.212905] [<c0379a14>] (uart_get_baud_rate) from [<bf07cf84>] (sc16is7xx_set_termios+0x1c4/0x374 [sc16is7xx])
[ 5592.213045] [<bf07cdc0>] (sc16is7xx_set_termios [sc16is7xx]) from [<c0379f04>] (uart_change_speed+0x5c/0x124)
```

Exactly these two messages are logged, every time I:

- open or close the connection to `/dev/ttySC0` with `minicom` or `cat`
- change the baudrate or other serial port settings in `minicom`

### Measurements

Measuring with a scope (including basic logic analyzing) I can see communication to the chip on the I2C line when I:

- open or close the connection to `/dev/ttySC0` with `minicom`
- change the baudrate or other serial port settings in `minicom`

Otherwise, there is no communication at all on the line. At the moment, I'm trying to analyze the sent bytes and check them with the datasheet, i.e. debugging the driver in a way.

Comment: One thing comes to my mind: does the choice between the kernel config variables SERIAL_SC16IS7XX_I2C and SERIAL_SC16IS7XX_SPI match the interface the hardware uses? Is the chip connected to I2C or SPI? Have you checked the logs for any messages from the driver?

Comment: What exactly do you want to configure? You can use IOCTLs, or `stty` on the commandline, to set baud rate etc. Your `minicom` test should show some input/output. You can configure the kernel module using options (see `modinfo`, `modprobe`).

Comment: @JohanMyréen the chip is connected via I2C, so I included only SERIAL_SC16IS7XX_I2C.
`dmesg` shows logs on setting the baudrate in minicom, otherwise none.

Comment: @dirkt if I understand correctly, you think that I don't need / there is not more configuration than what can be set in the serial tools (e.g. `minicom`)?
I figured, there would be more settings / possibilities, but I am probably wrong there..

Comment: Usually, the kernel driver (you didn't say which one you are using) should take care of all important configuration stuff, either via the IOCTL interface (which is also used by `stty`, `minicom` etc.), or otherwise (module options etc.). If it doesn't, you'll have to patch the kernel driver. I haven't read the datasheet, and as I don't know the driver, I haven't read the source code of it, either, but if you don't have a *particular* configuration you think you need and haven't found, you shouldn't worry. Unless something doesn't work.

Comment: @dirkt ok, thanks for that advise. Unfortunatley it doesn't work, so I guess I need to dig deeper (in the source code and on the hardware).

Comment: Please edit question with how you load the driver (`modprobe ...`), and what `dmesg` shows wrt. to the driver. Debug steps: Identify I2C bus, read registers directly with `i2c-tools` or similar. Verify `stty` sets up registers correctly wrt. baud rate etc. If you can, get a scope, verify that correct signals are sent/received on Tx/Rx pins.